# Could not load file or assembly in VS

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to move all my references into a seperate folder inside "Debug" folder called "references" to stop Debug folder getting filled up.

When changing a reference's "Copy Local" to false, it throws this error and displays "Application is in break mode" screen which is really strange?

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Could not load file or assembly 'NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The program '[7676] Server.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Any ideas? I know the path DOES exist, I entered the path and the .DLL file opens straight away.

Comment: but maybe it has dependancies

Comment: What do you mean when you say your bin folder is filling up?  It seems that you are not managing your dependencies correctly.  Firstly, I would not recommend that you try to avoid making any explicit references to .dll files and secondly, I would highly recommend that you make use of Paket or Nuget to manage your dependencies.

Comment: @DaffyPunk I suggest you sort your comments out before posting them, I said the debug folder was filling up, its filling up because I have about 20 .dll files, I use nuget and paket already, I just wanted to change their path.

Comment: @xozijow Extremely rude comment to someone that is trying to help you.  I was trying to determine why the number of DLL's is actually a problem for you.  You are interfering with the normal functioning of tools which have been written to abstract away the complexities of DLL management.  My question was perfectly valid as is evident by the fact that you have now broken your system towards an end with no real benefit.  Good luck sorting out these unnecessary issues you caused yourself, because I won't be helping you any further!